# no known conversion for argument 3 from 'void (MyClass::*)()' to 'void (*)()' when instantiating in constructor

Tags: c++, class, arduino, type-conversion

Supposedly a much asked question but I can't find any solutions searching high and low. I've come quite a bit, changing the way the members are declared and instantiating the Task object in the constructor now, but not there yet (and while I mostly know what I'm doing, I don't know the proper terms for many words - too new to this game).

In the actual script there are multiple such Task objects, all giving basically the same error message.

I'm trying to instantiate one class into another, and the problem is that I have to pass back a function.

The header file:

```
#ifndef HYDROMONITORMASTER_H
#define HYDROMONITORMASTER_H

#include <TaskScheduler.h>

class HydroMonitorMaster 
{
  public:
    HydroMonitorMaster (void);

  private:
    void readSensors(void);
    Scheduler ts;
    Task tReadSensors;
};
#endif
```

The .cpp file:

```
#include <HydroMonitorMaster.h>

HydroMonitorMaster::HydroMonitorMaster() : tReadSensors(10*1000, TASK_FOREVER,  &HydroMonitorMaster::readSensors, &ts, false) {}

void HydroMonitorMaster::readSensors() {}
```

And finally of course the error message that I get:

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Linux), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 230400, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorMaster.cpp: In constructor 'HydroMonitorMaster::HydroMonitorMaster()':
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorMaster.cpp:3:125: error: no matching function for call to 'Task::Task(int, int, void (HydroMonitorMaster::*)(), Scheduler*, bool)'
 HydroMonitorMaster::HydroMonitorMaster() : tReadSensors(10*1000, TASK_FOREVER,  &HydroMonitorMaster::readSensors, &ts, false) {}
                                                                                                                             ^
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorMaster.cpp:3:125: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorMaster.h:4:0,
                 from /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/HydroMonitor/src/HydroMonitorMaster.cpp:1:
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/TaskScheduler-master/src/TaskScheduler.h:347:1: note: Task::Task(long unsigned int, long int, void (*)(), Scheduler*, bool, bool (*)(), void (*)())
 Task::Task( unsigned long aInterval, long aIterations, void (*aCallback)(), Scheduler* aScheduler, bool aEnable, bool (*aOnEnable)(), void (*aOnDisable)() ) {
 ^
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/TaskScheduler-master/src/TaskScheduler.h:347:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'void (HydroMonitorMaster::*)()' to 'void (*)()'
exit status 1
```

The real issue appears to be in the end of the error: `no known conversion for argument 3 from 'void (HydroMonitorMaster::*)()' to 'void (*)()'` And I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: A pointer to a (non-static) member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-member function. A (non-static) member function needs an object to be called on, while non-member functions (and static member functions) don't need that. Either make your function a static member function, or use e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the constructor takes raw function pointers, I don't think `function` or `bind` will help.

Comment: Adding the `static` keyword to the function declarations in the .h file helps a lot - not completely there, yet, it seems I have to make many more member variables static as well - I omitted all those from the code that I posted, of course it's supposed to do some real work.